# AndroidStudio Dialog with Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dialog

[image]

When I was looking for tutorials about how to create a dialog with a spinner I found the following example on googles tutorial pages, but they didn't provide the code to it. Also by searching with google after spinner dialog tutorials I couldn't find such a well designed dialog.

So I would like to ask if somebody probably know the receive an equal/almost equal result? (I am talking about the left one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget in left fig is [NumberPicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.) , not spinner.

To create custom dialog, you could use [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment), the official doc give good examples. I personally think its better than any other tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Create a layout file with your Spinner in that layout...

In Activity, inflate your Layout with LayoutInflater like -

```
View view = getLayoutInflater(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
builder.setView(view).show();
```

Comment: Means, I can just create any Layout as long as I open it with the AlertDialog.Builder it will look similar to the one in the image? PS.: In the image we don't see an spinner but something similar, bc the spinner is something with a popup showing possible selection options, how is this element called?

Comment: @baxbear No, You will need to create a layout like that first... AlertDialog will show whatever is in the layout file.